# whitespace:nowrap - how can I truncate the overflowed text - rather than have it expand the element?

Tags: html, css, dom

[This plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mVC8AAeBfFeBYCyx1mQx?p=preview) demonstrates what I'm trying and failing to do.

I have some simple HTML:

```
  <div class =  "fixed-width-div"> 
    <label> hello world </label>
  </div>

  <div class ="fixed-width-div">        
    <label> adfkldjs sdklfjsdlkfjsdklfkj sdkfjsdlfjlsdkfj lsjdfklsdfjlsdjf lsdjfksdlfjskdf </label>
  </div>
```

I don't want the long labels wrapping, nor do I want them overflowing or expanding the parent element.

```
label {
  background-color: #ddd;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

}

.fixed-width-div {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: cyan;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;   
}
```

How can I acheive this?

I suspect it's actually a difficult problem - as that text *is* in the DOM and has to go somewhere right?

Comment: Please state exactly what you want. You only stated what you don't want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```css
label {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.fixed-width-div {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: cyan;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;   
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-width-div">
  <label>hello world</label>
</div>

<div class="fixed-width-div">
  <label>adfkldjs sdklfjsdlkfjsdklfkj sdkfjsdlfjlsdkfj lsjdfklsdfjlsdjf lsdjfksdlfjskdf</label>
</div>
```

Comment: for the purposes of this issue, yes! Thank you. The next step is to get it to work with the flex layout that's above in the example - but we'll see if i can get it from here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly you are after here, but if you add:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to your container div then it won't spill over or expand.

Now, I suspect you already know this and want to save your cyan padding-right of 5px. To do this, you need to add your labels to its own separate div with restricted width and then center that in your original container.

Hope this steers you down the right path.

Update with actual code:

```
.inner-container {
   width: 95px;
   overflow: hidden;
}

<div class ="fixed-width-div">
<div class="inner-container">
  <label> adfkldjs sdklfjsdlkfjsdklfkj sdkfjsdlfjlsdkfj lsjdfklsdfjlsdjf lsdjfksdlfjskdf </label>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: Old Way]

[image: New Way]